# Condicionales Javascript

Tags: javascript

una enunciado que dice:
Devuelve "true" si "numero" es 10 o 5
De lo contrario, devuelve "false"

```
function esDiezOCinco(numero) {
  if(numero == 10 || 5) {
    return true;
  }else if(numero != 10, numero != 5){
    return false;
  }
}
```

lo hice de esa manera, pero el test me dice que está mal, en la aprte donde retorna false:
¿como podría hacerlo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function esDiezOCinco(numero) {
  if(numero === 10 || numero === 5) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```